# I have a problem with Feed Parser between title and media:title

Tags: android

Here is the xml I want to parse

```
<item>
<title>Music Monday: Can 'The Whole Love' Compare to Wilco's Best?</title>
<link>...</link>
<comments>...</comments>
<pubDate>Mon, 19 Sep 2011 20:05:24 +0000</pubDate>
<media:title type="html">clairesuddath</media:title>
<media:thumbnail url="http://timenewsfeed.files.wordpress.com/2011/09/98079207.jpg?w=150"/>
</item>
```

This is the code I used

```
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        currentElement = false;
        if (currentFeedItem != null) {
            if(localName.equals("title")){
                currentFeedItem.setTitle(currentValue);
            } else if (localName.equals("link")) {
                currentFeedItem.setLink(currentValue);
            } else if (localName.equals("pubDate")) {
                String dateString = currentValue;
                try {
                    Date date = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
                    currentFeedItem.setPubDate(date);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    Log.e("RSSFeed", "ERROR", e);
                }
            } 
            else if (localName.equals("item")) {
                feedItemList.add(currentFeedItem);
            }
        }

    }
```

Every time i want to get title, i get media:title instead. How can I modified my code to solve this?

The other is how can I get url from media:thumbnail?

Thank you very much.

P.S. Sorry if my grammar bother you, I'm not good at English .

Answer (score 0):

I just encounter the same problem, use "qName" instead of "LocalName" will fix your problem